# Dataset/datatable is a value type or reference type

Tags: c#-4.0, value-type, reference-type

Is datatable/dataset is value type of reference type?

But the most important question in my mind is- "**how to find whether a type is a value type or reference type?**"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are both reference types.

You can look up the information on MSDN - if they are classes, they are reference types, if structs, value types.

See [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) and [`DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx). As you can see, they are both declared as classes.

Comment: Also you can check this article for further information about parameter passing: [Parameter Passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Type.IsValueType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isvaluetype.aspx) method.

Answer (score 2):

Both are **reference type**

```
DataTable dt = new  DataTable();

Type t = dt.GetType();

bool isValueType  = t.IsValueType;
```

isValueType will return `false`.